# Question about flying around hurricane

Tags: commercial-aviation

I'm supposed to fly from NYC to Jacksonville on Friday afternoon. If the forecast for Hurricane Florence holds, the storm should be somewhere over the Carolinas at that point. With neither NYC or Jax being directly impacted, can commercial airliners fly around the hurricane? Would it be likely that our flight would be cancelled/delayed because of a major hurricane being in the flight path? Thanks

Comment: Have you asked your airline?  I bet they tell you "we won't know until at least Thursday."

Answer (score 1):

Hurricanes move en masse pretty slow compared to a jet airliner.
Heck even compared to a small plane. It is not a problem to fly a path around them to avoid them.  Eventually the winds and rain will impact local travel, but the hurricane must be 'pretty close' for that - how close will depend on the aircraft size.  Wind/Rain/ceilings will impact small aircraft sooner than large jet airlines that fly hundreds of miles faster.